# When to modified maxPartitionBytes value in spark

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

I know that the value of `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` is 128MB by default, but I was wondering if that value is sufficient in most scenarios considering cases where more than 1 file is read (i.e three file ~10GB, ~68GB and ~5GB). And also if there is a limit to that value, maybe related to the cores memory.

Or if it is not really necessary to change it due to AQE, as is the case with shuffle partitions and coalesce.

Answer (score 0):

I think it still may be worth to play around this parameter. In general you if you want to change it you should consider your other settings (number of executors/memory/cores)

> "if there is a limit to that value, maybe related to the cores memory"

there is no limit but you should keep in mind what is your total execution memory for your executor and number of cores per executor. For example if you increase this parameter to 1 gb but you'll going to have only 4gb memory with 5 cores you may have problems

> Or if it is not really necessary to change it due to AQE, as is the
> case with shuffle partitions and coalesce.

AQE is going to optimize your partitions, thats true, but it will be able to do it after first shuffle. So you may face scenario in which you are going to create not optimal partitions just to fix them later